# WiX statement "CDATA[NOT Installed]" is not working

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.7

I am trying to make the DemoDatabaseDlg dialog conditional, so if it is the FIRST time the user is installing the installer then "DemoDatabaseDlg" should be displayed. If it is NOT the first time installation then skip this dialog and jump to the next dialog.

```
  <Publish Dialog="WelcomeDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="DemoDatabaseDlg">1</Publish>

  <Publish Dialog="DemoDatabaseDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="WelcomeDlg">
    <![CDATA[NOT Installed]]>
  </Publish>

  <Publish Dialog="DemoDatabaseDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="PrepareDlg">1</Publish>
  <Publish Dialog="ExitDialog" Control="Finish" Event="EndDialog" Value="Return" Order="999">1</Publish>
```

However, after the first installation, when I try to increase the version number and re-install again, I still CAN see the DemoDatabaseDlg dialog. How can I skip this dialog using CDATA conditions?

Comment: Are you also changing the ProductCode?

Comment: FWIW there's no such thing as "CDAATA conditions".  CDATA is merely escaping the text that proceeds. In this case it isn't even needed because the conditional expression NOT Installed doesn't contain any special characters that need escaping.

Answer (score 1):

Typically you have a Welcome dialog and a Maintenance dialog in the UI sequence as the first dialog.  It's hard to say for sure without seeing the rest of your code or an installation log file but my guess is you are doing major upgrades and changing the ProductCode property with each build. In this scenario  each new version is not yet installed from MSI's perspective.

Comment: I tried  taking a look at the log file, and I found out that there is an Action in the log file called AppSearch which return the value of 0 even though a previous version is already installed on my machine. Do you think this is where the problem is coming from?

Comment: No. Post your logs from the first and second installs.

Comment: AppSearch is not about older products installed. Look for the FindRelatedProducts in your new setup to see if it found an older version.